# Using React Hooks, how do I make a reusable component and parent component that utilize each other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, react-component

**What am I trying to do?**

Make a reusable React component that can work with the parent component, depending on what the parent wants.

**What is the code that currently tries to do that?**

ReusableComponent.js

```
import * from "react";

import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

export default function ReusableComponent() {
    const [championClass, setChampionClass] = useState("");
        
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setChampionClass(e.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <TextField
            onChange={handleChange}
            select
            value={championClass}
        >
            <MenuItem value={"Fighter"}>Fighter</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={"Mage"}>Mage</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={"Marksman"}>Marksman</MenuItem>
        </Textfield>
    );
```

ParentComponent.js

```
import * from "react";

import ReusableComponent from "../ReusableComponent";

export default function ParentComponent() {
    // There's gonna be other parents such as forest, mountain, etc.)
    const [underwaterChampionClass, setUnderwaterChampionClass] 
        = useState("");

    const handleUnderwaterChampionClass = (e) => {
        setUnderwaterChampionClass(e.target.value)
        console.log(underwaterChampionClass);
    }

    return (
        <ReusableComponent 
            championClass={underwaterChampionClass} 
            setChampionClass={handleUnderwaterChampionClass}
        />
    )
}
```

**What do I expect the result to be?**

That when I select a value from the dropdown from the parent, it reflects through the parent component through the "console.log".

**What is the actual result?**

Nothing is populating in the console.

**What I think the problem could be?**

I feel like I'm not connecting the components correctly and I'm not sure how to tackle this with React Hooks because multiple parent components will be using this reusable dropdown component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually using the props you are passing from `ParentComponent` to `ReusableComponent`, and are creating two separate states. You should change `ReusableComponent` to something like:

```
import * from "react";

import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

export default function ReusableComponent({
  value,
  handleChange
}) {
    return (
        <TextField
            onChange={e => handleChange(e.target.value)}
            select
            value={value}
        >
            <MenuItem value={"Fighter"}>Fighter</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={"Mage"}>Mage</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={"Marksman"}>Marksman</MenuItem>
        </Textfield>
    );
```

and `ParentComponent` to:

```
import * from "react";

import ReusableComponent from "../ReusableComponent";

export default function ParentComponent() {
    // There's gonna be other parents such as forest, mountain, etc.)
    const [underwaterChampionClass, setUnderwaterChampionClass] 
        = useState("");

    const handleUnderwaterChampionClass = (newChampionClass) => {
        setUnderwaterChampionClass(newChampionClass)
        console.log(underwaterChampionClass);
    }

    return (
        <ReusableComponent 
            value={underwaterChampionClass} 
            handleChange={handleUnderwaterChampionClass}
        />
    )
}
```